# Issues Printing Combiniations

Tags: python, combinations

The itertools function has no error but it also doesn't print anything once its complete.
My code is:

```
def comb(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
        if sorted(indices) == list(indices):
            print (indices)
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

I included the print statement but it doesn't print the total combinations it calculated.

Comment: Why would you create a list of integers as long as the input data, generate their permutations, use each permutation as a pair of indices into the original and yield the results? Oh, because you want to filter them to be ordered? That's what `itertools.combinations` is for; it directly replaces your entire function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on how generators work.  When you call `comb()` it returns a generator object.  You need to then do something with the generator object to get the objects returned from it.

```
from itertools import permutations

lst = range(4)
result = list(comb(lst, 2))  # output of print statement is now shown

print(result) # prints: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

`comb()` returns a generator object.  Then, `list()` iterates it and collects the values in a list.  At the time of iteration, your print statement fires.

Comment: I get this error:    for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
NameError: global name 'permutations' is not defined

Comment: You need to have an `import` statement.  I added one to my example.

Answer (score 1):

It returns you a [generator](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/generators.html) object. If you iterate through it you will see the printing. For example:

```
for x in comb(range(3),2):
    print "Printing here:", x
```

gives you:

```
(0, 1) # due to print statement inside your function
Printing here: (0, 1)
(0, 2) # due to print statement inside your function
Printing here: (0, 2)
(1, 2) # due to print statement inside your function
Printing here: (1, 2)
```

So, if you just want to print the combinations line by line, remove the print statement inside your function and just convert it to a list or iterate through it. You can print those line by line as:

```
print "\n".join(map(str,comb(range(4),3)))
```

gives you

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```